# Python reports key error when parsing a config file via cron

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, cron

I have a cron job scheduled that calls a python script with a command line argument. The argument passed into the program corresponds to the section of the config file to read. The program works as expected when I run it by hand but reports a key error via cron. The output of the cron is:

```
    foobar = config[section]['key1']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'section1'
```

Is this some funny business with quotes and the way the command line argument is being interpreted as a sting?

The cron job is:

`25 13 * * * python3 /home/user/script.py section1`

Here's an except of the python program:

```
import sys
import configparser


section = sys.argv[1]

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

foobar = config[section]['key1']
```

And the config file is:

```
[section1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[section2]
key1 = value3
key2 = value4
```

Comment: Is it actually finding the config file? I ask because one of the unusual behaviors of ConfigParser is that it doesn't raise an exception if the file is missing - it just treats a missing file as an empty config file.

Comment: Also, since you're using a relative path `config.read('config.ini')`, you could be having a problem where the current working directory when running under cron is different from the directory you're normally using to run the script. Try an absolute path to the config file.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The pull path is needed for the config file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to provide the full path to the config script.